# set targetNameSpace using Go

Tags: soap, service, web, namespaces, go

I am using Go for soap web service.
When I call the webservice I do like this.

```
request := fmt.Sprintf(para)
cli := new(http.Client)
//http.Header["http://webservice.ei"]="notify"
resp, err := cli.Post("http://127.0.0.1:8751/WebRoot/services/SecurtyWebService/notify?wsdl&targetNamespace=http://webservice.ei","text/xml;charset=utf-8",bytes.NewBufferString(request))
```

I get this error.

```
<faultstring>namespace mismatch require http://webservice.ei found none</faultstring>
```

I learn that the server require a targetNameSpace para. I also know that in java. People fix this by using:

```
 QName opAddEntry = new QName("http://webservice.ei", "notify");
```

But I find there's no way for me to add this parameter.
Can anyone gime me some advice on how to set the namespace when calling the soap webservice in go?

Comment: Presumably the fault relates to (a) the nature of the service you're trying to access, and (b) the body of the request you're sending.  You've left out information about both in your question, so it is difficult to offer any help.

Comment: Much thanks for your answer.For A) The service itself is correct. We just ignore it. For B) the body I am sending is an XML string. Very likely I am doing it a wrong way. My question is how to set the `namespace` when calling the web service in go ?  any  possible advice is ok. I am willing to try.